# Resulting array is the subtraction of two arrays in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Without running scripts, is it possible to have `=small(array, k)` accept an array term as `((A:An)-(A1; A5; ... ; Ax)).`

This `((A:An)-(A1; A5; ... ; Ax))`, in my reasoning, should return `A2; A3; A4; A6; A7; ... ; An`, and the ommited part (...) will not contain `Ax`.

Excel is returning #VALUE when calculating the `((A:An)-(A1; A5; ... ; Ax))` part.

I guess it can be done in VBA, but it seems it should be possible to have this result within the formula bar, somehow.

Can someone cast some light on the issue?

E.g: `(A1:A5-(A2;A4))` should result in `(A1; A3; A5)`.

Comment: Are you intending on taking one array away from another? And are those two inner arrays the same length? I would expect array lengths typically to be equal then entered as  an array formula (Ctrl + Shift + Enter) within the outer small call

Comment: The second array (the one being taken away) consists of some cells or ranges within the first array. The resulting array should be the one considered by =small.

E.g: (A1:A5-(A2;A4)) should result in (A1; A3; A5)

Comment: I may be wrong but typically the arrays need to be of equal length for array based Excel functions.

Comment: I think it is possible. Better put some sample data & expected output. There may some other approach to achieve your output.

Comment: I'd research `FILTER()`

Comment: I'll give `Filter()` a try. I'll provide some sample data & expected output later if I can't come up with a solution. And I'll be sure to post a solution if I find one. For now, thanks a lot, guys.

Comment: Sorry to pour cold water but it's not possible to say "A1:A5 excluding A2 and A4". Your use of "minus" casts fog on the issue. Use "exclude" and you arrive at filtering. But it's not possible to filter on cell or array addresses, only on cell or array elements' values. Therefore you should define the task like "A1:A5 excluding elements with value < 3", for example. Criteria information is missing from your question which, therefore, is Mission Impossible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you could try out `FILTER()`:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=FILTER(A1:A5,NOT(MMULT(--(ROW(A1:A5)={2;4}),{1,1})))
```

I've translated `{A2,A4}` into an horizontal array of numbers. In your case you may also just use, say `C1:C2` and refer to that through `TRANSPOSE(C1:C2)`. Furthermore I wrote the 2nd parameter of `MMULT()` out as an vertical array, but you may (using the same data) refer to `SEQUENCE(COUNT(C1:C2),,,0)`. Effectively, making it look like:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=FILTER(A1:A5,NOT(MMULT(--(ROW(A1:A5)=TRANSPOSE(C1:C2)),SEQUENCE(COUNT(C1:C2),,,0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading some of the exchange, not sure if you are after something like this.

`=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$3,0)),"",$A$1:$A$5),ROWS($A$1:$A1)),"")`

You may or may not have to implement this formula through Array Entry depending on your Excel version.

Here `Column A` holds `A to An` elements and `Column B` holds `A to Ax` elements. Depending on your requirement, swap positions TRUE and FALSE parts to get desired list.

Answer (score 0):

**To subtract A2 and A4 in range A1:A5**

1] Result put in separate cells

In `B1`, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($1:$5)/ISNA(MATCH(A$1:A$5,IF({1,0},A$2,A$4),0)),ROW(A1))),"")
```

2] Result merge in a single cell

In `C1`, array (CSE) formula :

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,IF(N(IF(1,ISNA(MATCH(A1:A5,IF({1,0},A2,A4),0)))),A1:A5,""))
```

[image]

Comment: I got it to work by changing to semicolons. Guess my region uses it instead of normal commas. 
I don't understand the array for `aggregate`. Being specific, I don't understand the / dividing the `row()` and the `isna()`. How can I further study this?